# No module named ez_setup

Tags: python-2.7

I was trying to install pyttsx-1.0 for python 2.7.4 using cmd.

Typed the following :

```
    satup.py install
```

in cmd and got the error message

```
    No module named ez_setup
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the conflict myself.

I had previously installed Panda3d.

Actually the path variables of python were changed when I installed Panda3d.
So I reinstalled python 2.7 without uninstalling panda 3d and then the module got installed easily.

Thanks to all those who tried to help

Answer (score 1):

are you using your PC user as admin? if you don't- try to change to the admin user and try again.

is python installed already? try to install without cmd and then try to run it on cmd again.

Comment: I am admin user. yes python is installed.(But then my default python was overriden by panda python as i was creating projects in panda3d before. But as far as I know panda python is same as python 2.7 and all modules which is provided by python 2.7 are present in panda python.

Comment: And it cannot be installed without cmd

Comment: This was actually useful in a roundabout way.  I had previously tried pip installing ez_setup and it told me it was already installed, yet that error was still showing up.  Somehow resolved it by pip installing ez_setup in admin mode cmd console.